# syntax error python 'if' and 'else' statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm getting this syntax error in my code and I can't figure out if it's an indentation error or something else (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alazd.png).

```
# Creating a program that gives us the name,score and grade with variation in score and grade! A
name = input("Enter namez")
# print("name:", name)
print()

score = input("Enter scorez")
# print("score:", score)

score = int(score)
if score >= 75:
    grade = 'Excellent'
elif score >= 60:
    grade = 'Very good'
elif score >= 50
    grade = 'Quite good'
elif score >= 40
    grade = 'Not Bad'
elif score >= 30
    grade = 'Pretty Bad'
elif score >= 20
    grade = 'Horibble'
else: grade = 'Appauling'
print()

print('name:', name, 'score:', score, ' and grade:', grade)
print()

print('So,', name, 'you got a score of', score, 'and hence culminates that your grade becomes', grade, '.')
```

Comment: You forgot to add`:` after each condition. You have `score >= 50` but should be `score >=50:`

Comment: It looks like you're missing a bunch of colons.

Comment: I think you forgot : ?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed number of ":" in elif conditions and in last four conditions, set the indention by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `semi-colons (:)` in `elif` condition. And then indentation too is not correct in last 3 assignment to `grade`.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper indentation to mark blocks of your code.

Your `elif` statements are missing colons.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations

> Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not).

The exception to that is when `=` is used to set named parameters.

That said, you could turn your code into a reusable function.

```
def grade(score):
    """ Return a grade based on score."""

    rank = ''

    if score >= 75:
        rank = 'Excellent'
    elif score >= 60:
        rank = 'Very good'
    elif score >= 50:
        rank = 'Quite good'
    elif score >= 40:
        rank = 'Not bad'
    elif score >= 30:
        rank = 'Pretty bad'
    elif score >= 20:
        rank = 'Horrible'
    else:
        rank = 'Appalling'

    return rank

name = input('Enter name: ')
score = int(input('Enter score: '))    
report_card = {'Name': name, 'Score': score, 'Grade': grade(score)}

print(report_card)
```

Test run:

```
Enter name: X
Enter score: 90
{'Name': 'X', 'Score': 90, 'Grade': 'Excellent'}
```